# JADE & NodeJS access JSON object property array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, pug

I have a JSON object

```
{ "ID": "Test", "Data": [ "Line1", "Line2" ] }
```

And the following JADE Code

```
h4 {{object.ID}}:
    ul
      each line in object.Data
        li= line
```

I can display the ID  but I cant iterate over the array it errors out on the each line with "Cant Read Property "Data" of undefined,
doing a

```
p {{object}}
```

prints the above JSON just fine..

any ideas why this is?

Update: The Object is being passed in from an angular controller.

Comment: Try doing a ` - console.log(object)` in your template and see what it actually is

Comment: I think it should be `li {{line}}`

Comment: It's not getting that far. The Error is on the EACH line. It's not able to see the property Data of object yet rendering out the whole object in a paragraph shows the Data array

Comment: Doing a `p {{object.Data}}` shows the array just fine. Trying a `each line in {{object.Data}}` fails with unexpected `{`

Comment: console,log gives cannot read property 'Data' of undefined

Comment: it seems that "object" is undefined in the template however how come i can access it with `{{object}}`?

Comment: How did you pass the variable `object` to the jade render? Could you please show your snippet?

Comment: in the angular controller it was assigned to `$scope.object` I'll add the snippet when i get home.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like it was the angular.

```
li(ng-repeat='note in object.Data') {{note}}
```

not the JADE.